# Test function vanishing at origin, divided by x is still a test function?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given an infinitely differentiable function on the real line that vanishes at the origin, divide it by x.  Clearly the result is differentiable, but I think it is also infinitely differentiable--is there an easy way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(x)=x\int_0^1 f'(xt)\, dt.$

Comment: Thanks, this works, but seems kind of unmotivated... Is there any other intuition for this?

Comment: We start with $f(x)-f(0) = \int_0^xf'(t)\,dt,$ make a simple change of variables, and voila. The FTC seems pretty well movitivated to me,

Comment: I see, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this with Taylor series?